# Non spin-singlet ground states of antiferromagnetic Heisenberg model

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

To be specific, let's consider a finite lattice (in any dimension) with even number of sites, each containing a spin-1/2 interacting with other spin-1/2's via antiferromagnetic Heisenberg coupling. In such a setting, are there examples of systems which has non-spin singlet ground states?

It is known from Marshall's theorem that for a *bipartite* lattice (with equal size sublattices), the ground state is a global spin singlet.

Comment: Consider the the geometry of a square (4 sites) plus a coupling between just one of the diagonals.
I think that the ground-state is degenerate: the energy of S=0 subspace is the same of zero-magnetization state in S=1 subspace. The reason is as follows: locally, the former looks like a singlet along the connected diagonal, whilst latter is a zero-magnetization triplet. I wrote the hamiltonian as the difference between fully connected (~casimir) and originally non-occurring terms in H to get this "ansatz". Have not done the calculations explicitly, but you can check and get back to me.